# highest jvm arguments to speed up my java program

Tags: java, memory, time, jvm, jtable

I am building a JTABLE that is made of about 40000 rows, my program takes about 30 min to run and then I am not even able to see the JTABLE, the program is still running but no JTABLE is displayed, I suspect the reason for that is that my program is too slow and takes too many resources. Which flags should I use to increase the JVM and make my program as fast as I can? 
Which flags should I use for -Xms and -Xmx? How can I manage to display my JTABLE?

Comment: I think you need to fix your code. There's no magical "make things go fast" flag, and you don't even know why your program is slow (but I bet you've written really inefficient code that works fine for simple situations and a few dozen rows).

Comment: Can you post the code to generate the table with the 40K rows?

Comment: I have been able to display my JTABLE before and I am no longer able to display it now

Comment: First, I am reading data from a database and that takes about 10 min https://github.com/mouna2/SpoonProcessorFinal/blob/master/src/main/java/Gantt/DatabaseReading2Gantt.java and then I am processing that data and making some calculations and then displaying the results in a table and here is the code for that https://github.com/mouna2/SpoonProcessorFinal/blob/master/src/main/java/Gantt/DatabaseReading2Gantt.java

Comment: You need to profile your application to see what it is taking so long. a Table of 40K records is easy to process, takes some time to download from a database, but can be very difficult to render efficiently.

Comment: A constructor with >1500 lines of code… that’s where I quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are learning Java. First of all, I recommend you reading these two books:

- **Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship** (Robert C. Martin)
- **Effective Java** 2017 (Joshua Bloch)

In your code, you are posting things like full path directories and your username:

> spoon.addInputResource("C:\Users\**mouna**\ownCloud\Share\ganttproject\ganttprojectCopy");

Or a connection url:

> DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasegantt", "**root**", "**123456**");

I will give you some advices:

- Divide your algorithm in two: fecth the results from database and then paint them in the JTable.
- Paginate the results if possible.
- Do not use the String operator "+" inside loops, instead you should use a StringBuilder.
- You can use a StopWatch (Spring utility) to trace where your code is slow and improve it.